Question regarding sigma finite set proof
It’s a well known fact that, If $f$ is integrable, then $\{x\in X\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$ is sigma finite. Here is a proof : If $f$ is integrable, then $\{x\in X\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$ is sigma finite
Now, the answer reads  “….   $1_{E_n}(x)\leq n|f(x)|$ for every $x\in X$ so that: $$\mu(E_n)=\int1_{E_n}d\mu\leq\int n|f|d\mu=n\int |f|d\mu<\infty”$$
My question is : How do we know that $\space n\int |f|d\mu<\infty$ when n goes to infinity ? I am misunderstanding something?
Thanks.
Edit : The reason of my doubts is that in other similar result ( I think its similar) : For $\int f < \infty$, the measure of the set of points where $f=\infty$ is zero. , the proof let n go to infinity. In both exercises you have a set that is the result of countable union/intersection of sets, but only one proof uses limit n to infinity.

You just need $\space n\int |f|d\mu<\infty$ for every fixed $n$. No need to let $n \to \infty$.

@geetha290krm I made an Edit.
